# Bootstrap modal works but doesn't display

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, bootstrap-modal

I've searching for various days an answer to my predicament but I can't find it.
I have a jsp code where I include two modals and when I try to display one of them, it doesn't display but the element shows up (in the monitor there aren't any changes, but the focus changes on the modal allow me to interact with the elements of the modal such as input fields)

And the browser's console doesn't show any error

this is my code:
index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Ejercicio 1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">Ejercicio</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-2 sidenav" id="info">
        <!-- añadir información del elemento seleccionado -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 text-left">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h1>Tabla de Empleados</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <%@include file="tablaEmpleados.jsp" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h1>Diferencias</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h2>Request</h2>
                        <p>Aquí, los atributos solo permanecen cuando la petición
                        esté completa, o cuando se pasa de un servlet a otro y 
                        son utiles cuando se necesita pasar información especifica
                        del lado de servlet a jsp.</p><br>
                        <p>Un ejemplo es el resultado de una consulta.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h2>Session</h2>
                        <p>Aquí, los atributos permanecen activos mientras la
                        sesión este activa, ya que se espera que haya peticiónes
                        relacionadas. Los atributos de sesion no se pueden pasar
                        de un servlet a otro. Son utiles cuando se requiere
                        pasar información constantemente por una sesion</p><br>
                        <p>Un ejemplo es la identificación de un usuario.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 sidenav">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                <button name="BotonAgregar" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalAgregar">
                    <span class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></span> Agregar
                </button> <br>
                <button name="BotonEditar" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalModificar" disabled>
                    <span class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Editar
                </button> <br>
                <button name="BotonEliminar" class="btn btn-danger" id="Eliminar" disabled>
                    <span class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Editar
                </button>
            </div> <!--botones de agregar, eliminar y editar -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <%@include file="../Modals/modalAgregar.jsp" %>
    <%@include file="../Modals/modalModificar.jsp" %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/popper.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

tablaEmpleados.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:include page="../app/modulo/EmpleadosServlet.do" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<table class="table table-hover" id="tablaEmpleados">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Telefono</td>
            <td>CURP</td>
            <td>Correo</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="cuerpo">
        <c:forEach items="${Empleado}" var="item">
            <tr class="fila">
                <td class="data nombre">${item.nombre}</td>
                <td class="data telefono">${item.telefono}</td>
                <td class="data curp">${item.curp}</td>
                <td class="data correo">${item.correo}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

modalAgregar.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<div id="ModalAgregar" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar empleado</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="Agregar">
                    <input type="hidden" name="event" id="evm" value="1">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control nombre" name="nombre">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control telefono" name="telefono">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control curp" name="curp">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control correo" name="correo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-send" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit" value="Agregar empleado">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

modalModificar.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<div id="ModalModificar" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modificar empleado</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="Modificar">
                    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="2">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control nombre" name="nombre">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control telefono" name="telefono">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control curp" name="curp" disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control correo" name="correo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-send" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit" value="Modificar empleado">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ExpRegular = /[[a-z]\s]+/i;
    var ExpRegularTel = /[0-9][0-9][0-9](-)[0-9](-)[0-9][0-9](-)[0-9][0-9](-)[0-9][0-9]/;
    var ExpRegularCurp = /[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}[A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}/;
    var ExpRegularCorreo = /([a-z]|[0-9]|.|-|_)+@[a-z]+(.|[a-z])+/i;

    var tabla = $("#tablaEmpleados").DataTable();
    var nombre = "";
    var telefono = "";
    var curp = "";
    var correo = "";

    bootbox.setLocale("es");

    $('#tablaEmpleados tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        nombre = tabla.row(this).data()[0];
        telefono = tabla.row(this).data()[1];
        curp = tabla.row(this).data()[2];
        correo = tabla.row(this).data()[3];
        $("button").each(function (index) {
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        });


        //$(".nombre").get(1).val(nombre);
        //$(".telefono").get(1).val(telefono);
        //$(".curp").get(1).val(curp);
        //$(".correo").get(1).val(correo);
        $("#info").empty();
        $("#info").append("<p>Nombre: " + nombre + "</p><br><p>Telefono: " + telefono + "</p><br><p>CURP: " +
                curp + "</p><br><p> Correo: " + correo + "</p>");
    });

    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        var index = parseInt($(""));
        event.preventDefault();
        if (ExpRegular.exec($(".nombre").get()).val() === null || ExpRegular.exec($(".nombre").val()) !== $(".nombre").val()) {
            bootbox.alert({
                title: "Error",
                size: "large",
                message: "Error: El nombre no es valido"
            });
        } else if (ExpRegularTel.exec($(".telefono").val()) === null && ExpRegularTel.exec($(".telefono").val()) !== $(".telefono").val()) {
            bootbox.alert({
                title: "Error",
                size: "large",
                message: "Error, el telefono no es valido.<br> Recuerde que el formato debe ser: xxx-x-xx-xx-xx"
            });
        } else if (ExpRegularCurp.exec($(".curp").val()) !== null && ExpRegularCurp.exec($(".curp").val()) === $(".curp").val()) {
            bootbox.alert({
                title: "Error",
                size: "large",
                message: "Error, la CURP no es valido.<br> Recuerde que el formato debe ser: ABCD123456EFGHIJ78"
            });
        } else if (ExpRegularCorreo.exec($(".correo").val()) !== null && ExpRegularCorreo.exec($(".correo").val()) === $(".correo").val()) {
            bootbox.alert({
                title: "Error",
                size: "large",
                message: "Error, el correo no es valido."
            });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: "app/modulo/EmpleadosServlet.do",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    bootbox.alert({
                        title: "Exito",
                        size: "small",
                        message: data
                    });
                },
                error: function (x, estado, exception) {
                    bootbox.alert({
                        title: "Error",
                        size: "small",
                        message: estado + " <br>" + exception
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $("#Eliminar").click(function () {
        bootbox.confirm({
            title: "Confirmación requerida",
            size: "large",
            message: "¿Realmente quiere eliminar a este empleado? <br> Nombre: "
                    + nombre + "<br> Telefono: " + telefono + "<br> CURP: " + curp + "<br> Correo: " + correo,
            callback: function (resultado) {
                if (resultado) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "app/modulo/EmpleadosServlet.do",
                        data: {
                            event: "1",
                            curp: curp
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (data) {
                            bootbox.alert({
                                title: "Exito",
                                size: "small",
                                message: data
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (x, estado, exception) {
                            bootbox.alert({
                                title: "Error",
                                size: "small",
                                message: estado + " <br>" + exception
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry., i couldnt see a bootstrap modal initialization.

Comment: I use buttons like this one
<button name="BotonAgregar" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalAgregar">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **missing bootstrap javascript**.

Try adding this CDN version below to see if it works:
(also worth trying to keep the modal on the same .jsp (without importing/including it)

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I was adding a bootstrap javascript. However I was using the bootstrap beta 4.0.0 and changing to the CDN you've provided it worked.

I guess the 4.0.0 isn't compartible with modals yet.

Comment: yeah that is a honest mistake. Great to hear it works now!